# Why did Teddy ask to change the place where the picture was about to be taken?

Tags: character, analysis, memento

In the end of *Memento* (and beginning of its story), Lenny wants to take a picture of Teddy. 
Does anybody have a clue why Teddy asked to change the place where the picture was about to be taken? 
Would there be any possible hint of who was the murderer of Lenny's wife on the background or scenario? 
Feeling intrigued....

Comment: Teddy was showing Lenny the corpse of a person he killed thinking it was the guy who destroyed his family and life.

Comment: A good way to figure out Memento is to watch the chronological version that was released on the DVD Extras

Comment: @Tetsujin Well that helps, but it spoils the *fun*.

Comment: It's a bit anorak, but watching the cinema release followed by the chronological is nicely palindromic ;)

Answer (score 2):

A different angle would probably have revealed that the two had met before at the Discount Inn. I think Teddy just didn't want him to know this because it would have hindered possible future manipulations of Lenny.